# No se toman correctamente valores de latitud y longitud en llamada AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy tratando de descubrir el error de llamada ajax. Trabajo con woocommerce.
Al completarse dos campos Latitud y Longitud en un formulario, cuando quiero pasar esas dos variables  `dato1lat` y `dato2long` e incluirlas en PHP, no los toma y los resultados que muestran `$origen = new Origen ($dato3, $dato2 );` son erróneos.

Así creé los campos adicionales en el check out:

```
         add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'add_custom_billing_field', 20, 1 );
        function add_custom_billing_field($billing_fields) {
        

            $billing_fields['billing_lat'] = array(
        'label'     => 'Latitud',
         'required'  => true,
         'class'     => array('form-row-wide' ),
         'placeholder' => 'Latitud',
         'clear'     => true,
         'priority' => 65
         ); 
        
           $billing_fields['billing_lon'] = array(
        'label'     => 'Longitud',
         'required'  => true,
         'class'     => array('form-row-wide' ),
         'placeholder' => 'Longitud',
         'clear'     => true,
         'priority' => 66
         ); 
        
            return $billing_fields;
            
        
        }
```

Estas celdas se autocompletan al escribir la dirección con la latitud y long provistas por google:

```
   $('#billing_lat').val(lat);
   $('#billing_lon').val(lng);
   var dato1lat = $('#billing_lat').val();
   var dato2long = $('#billing_lon').val();
   // console.log(dato1lat );
   // console.log(dato2long );

     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/wp-content/plugins/test/includes/class-wc-shipping-test.php',
    data: {dato1lat:dato1lat, dato2long:dato2long},
    success: function (result) {
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                     
                 }
      });
```

Y en este archivo PHP  *class-wc-shipping-test.php* (misma carpeta) necesito llamarlos para completar la clase calculate shipping que arroja el costo del envío.

```
public function calculate_shipping( $packages = array() ) {

....
if(isset($_POST['dato1lat'])){
$dato3 = $_POST['dato1lat'];
$dato2 = $_POST['dato2long'];
}    
   

$origen = new Origen ($dato3, $dato2 );
$destino = ....;
....
        
$this->add_rate( $rate );
 }
```

Comment: deberias agregar el html minimo necesario para poder ayudarte.

Comment: gracias @Riven complete mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('#billing_lat').val(lat);
 $('#billing_lon').val(lng);
 var dato1lat = $('#billing_lat').val();
 var dato2long = $('#billing_lon').val();
 // console.log(dato1lat );
 // console.log(dato2long );

 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: '/wp-content/plugins/test/includes/class-wc-shipping-test.php',
 data: {'dato1lat':dato1lat, 'dato2long':dato2long},
 success: function (result) {
 $('body').trigger('update_checkout');

             }
 });
```

Debes enviar los nombres de los campos de tu objeto entre '